# Ajax принимает в не те данные в ответ

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-form

ajax отправляет форму, все работает

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../profile/controllers/register_controller.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            'validEmail': validEmail,
            'validName': validName,
            'validPassword': validPassword,
            'validPassword2': validPassword2
        },
        beforeSend: function () {

            $("#do_register").prop("disable", true);
        },
        success: function (data) {

            alert(data.result);
            $("#do_register").prop("disable", false);
        },
        error: function (data) {
        }
    })
```

php ee принимает, тоэе все работает

```
<?php
namespace controllers;

$registerController = new RegisterController();
$registerController->register();

class RegisterController {

public function register() {

        $errors = array();
        $arrayFields = array(
            'name' => $_REQUEST['validName'],
            'email' => $_REQUEST['validEmail'],
            'password' => $_REQUEST['validPassword'],
            'password2' => $_REQUEST['validPassword2']
        );

        if ( isset($arrayFields['name']) ) {

        foreach ($arrayFields as $fieldName => $oneField) {
            if ($oneField == '' || !isset($oneField)) {
                $errors[$fieldName] = 'Required field';
            }
        }

        if (!filter_var($arrayFields['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
            $errors['email'] = 'Email is incorrect';

        if (iconv_strlen($arrayFields['name']) < 4)
            $errors['name'] = 'Name must be more than 4 characters';

        if (iconv_strlen($arrayFields['password']) < 6) {

            $errors['password'] = 'Password must be more than 6 characters';
        } else
            if ($arrayFields['password'] != $arrayFields['password2'])
                $errors['password2'] = 'Passwords do not match';

        if (empty($errors)) {

            $array = array('result' => 'success');
            echo json_encode($array);
            $db = new DBClass(SERVER, USER, PASS, DBNAME);
            $db->insert('user', [$arrayFields['email'],$arrayFields['password'], $arrayFields['name']], 'email, password, name');

        } else {

            $array = array('result' => 'error', 'text_error' => $errors);
            echo json_encode($array);

        }
    }
}
}
```

Но я получаю помимо json {"result":"success"} вот это

( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'controllers\DBClass' not found in /Library/WebServer/Documents/profile/controllers/register_controller.php on line *70*
( ! ) Error: Class 'controllers\DBClass' not found in /Library/WebServer/Documents/profile/controllers/register_controller.php on line *70*
Call Stack
#TimeMemoryFunctionLocation
10.0107383432{main}(  ).../register_controller.php**:**0
21.5552383672controllers\RegisterController->register(  ).../register_controller.php**:**5

Если заккоментировать вызов и работу с BD - всё отлично, алёрт работает

Только начал учить php и ajax, наверное глупая ошибка, но справиться никак не могу

Comment: У вас же пишет, что класс не найден `'controllers\DBClass' not found`. https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.php

Comment: В этом и суть, класс то есть и если отправлять форму просто POST то база работает и я не понимаю, как мне правильно ее вызвать, чтобы ajax не ругался

Comment: @Ringo она работает потому что в ошибке вы не обращаетесь к классу `DBClass`. Вам надо просто его подключить, как вы вообще классы "собираете"?

Comment: Вот тут $db = new DBClass(SERVER, USER, PASS, DBNAME);